# How to identify a row or a key in Android Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I need to identify each row or keys in a row.

Since row or key does not have "id" attribute,we cannot find it using findViewById.

Iam wondering is there any way of identifying rows and keys in the keyboard.You can find the keyboard's xml file below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:verticalGap="0px"
android:keyHeight="60dp" >

<Row>
    <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
    <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
    <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4"/>
    <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
    <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6"/>
    <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7"/>
    <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
    <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9"/>
    <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>

<Row>
    <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
    <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e"/>
    <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
    <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
    <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
    <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u"/>
    <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="i"/>
    <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="o"/>
    <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="a" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="115" android:keyLabel="s"/>
    <Key android:codes="100" android:keyLabel="d"/>
    <Key android:codes="102" android:keyLabel="f"/>
    <Key android:codes="103" android:keyLabel="g"/>
    <Key android:codes="104" android:keyLabel="h"/>
    <Key android:codes="106" android:keyLabel="j"/>
    <Key android:codes="107" android:keyLabel="k"/>
    <Key android:codes="108" android:keyLabel="l"/>
    <Key android:codes="35,64" android:keyLabel="\# \@" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="-1" android:keyLabel="CAPS" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="122" android:keyLabel="z"/>
    <Key android:codes="120" android:keyLabel="x"/>
    <Key android:codes="99" android:keyLabel="c"/>
    <Key android:codes="118" android:keyLabel="v"/>
    <Key android:codes="98" android:keyLabel="b"/>
    <Key android:codes="110" android:keyLabel="n"/>
    <Key android:codes="109" android:keyLabel="m"/>
    <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="."/>
    <Key android:codes="63,33,58" android:keyLabel="\? ! :" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
<Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
    <Key android:codes="44" android:keyLabel="," android:keyWidth="10%p"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="47" android:keyLabel="/" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
    <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="SPACE" android:keyWidth="40%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
    <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyLabel="DEL" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
    <Key android:codes="-4" android:keyLabel="DONE" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
</Row>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you would like to do by identifying the keys of the keyboard.

If you want to change the appearance of the keys, you can get the list of the keys in `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method of your `KeyboardView` class (`public class YoursKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {...})`:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
    for (Key key : keys) {
        switch (key.codes[0]) {
            //Your Key Codes...
        }
    }
}
```

which will identify your keys by the `android:codes="[your key code]"` which you defined in your xml.

Or like this where you want to override the labels of your keys on long press:

```
@Override
protected boolean onLongPress(Key key) {
    switch (key.codes[0]) {
        //Your Key Codes...
    }

    return super.onLongPress(key);
}
```